# python3, Want to set variables like they are increasing

Tags: python

How to take middle number and put in middle of min and max?

```
x=input('Pirveli: ')
y=input('Meore: ')
z=input('Mesame: ')
list = (ord(x),ord(y),ord(z))
print(min(list),(MIDDLENUMBER HERE),max(list))
```

Comment: Does your list always have exactly three numbers?

Comment: no, actually it's ord(x) i mean

Comment: your "list" (very bad name, hides a built-in function) is actually a tuple

Comment: I did not mean to ask whether it has three _numbers_, but whether there are always exactly _three_ things in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can sort the list, and you'll get what you need.

```
> lst = [4, 5, 3]
> lst.sort()
> lst
[3, 4, 5]
```

You can also use `sorted` in a more general way on iterable objects. For example, given a tuple with `x`, `y`, `z`:

```
> x = 6
> y = 2
> z = 3
> sorted((x, y, z))
[2, 3, 6]
```

Comment: like if x=10 y=30 z=20 it will print (10,30) i want it to print (10,20,30)

Comment: i edited post, i want them to post numbers as increasing :/

Comment: Might also use tuple unpacking to assign to three variables: `low, mid, high = sorted(lst)`

Comment: `sort` sorts them in increasing order. I'm not sure what you need

Comment: In the example code he is actually creating a tuple instead of a list, so maybe using `sorted` is a better recommendation?